# Equations solvable for p

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the following equations:
$$y=x[p+\sqrt{1+p^2}]$$
$$\text{where, p}=\frac{dy}{dx}$$
I can't understand how to start..please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subtract $xp$ from both sides and square, gives
\begin{eqnarray*}
y^2-2xyp \color{yellow}{+x^2p^2}= x^2  \color{yellow}{+x^2p^2}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Should be a doddle from here ?
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{dy}{dx} =\frac{y^2-x^2}{2xy}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Now sub $y=ux$.

Comment: Please tell the next step...

Answer (score 1):

Starting from Donald Splutterwit's answer:
$$\frac{dy}{dx} =\frac{y^2-x^2}{2xy}$$
$$2yy'x ={y^2-x^2}$$
$$x(y^2)'-y^2=-x^2$$
$$\frac {x(y^2)'-y^2}{x^2}=-1$$
$$\left (\frac {y^2}{x} \right )'=-1$$
Integrate to get the final answer.